# What is the significance of the multiplicative and additive identities? What can they tell us?

Tags: trigonometry

I have been aware of the these identities, the multiplicative and additive are widely known and introduced in most introductory mathematics classes.However, until I has begun to learn more about the Pythagorean identity I was amazed. With this simple formula it was possible to find the any trigonometric ratio with just one of them known. So it got me thinking what about the multiplicative and additive identities. What can they do for us?

Comment: It provides a basis for us to recursively define multiplication in terms of the multiplicative identity, as well as addition in terms of the additive identity.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that the multiplicative and additive identities are just more familiar representations of complex multiplication/exponentiation (there's a connection through De Moivre's formula).

Comment: You might want to be more specific about what you mean by multiplicative and additive identities (you don't even need to write down all of them, just enough examples to let the reader fill in the rest).  Most people on this site will, upon seeing the title of this question, assume that you are asking about the numbers $1$ and $0$!

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I mean.